# ESXi - exclusive, hardwired cores assignment to specific VM

Tags: esxi, hypervisor

I running 5 VMs on Xeon E5-4640 (12 cores, 24 threads). Two of them are virtual desktops, which must have guaranteed some performance (2 cores per desktop will be enough).
Is there any way to assign directly vCPUs to physical cores? I know it isn't optimal solution, but it's only for now.

Any ideas? I heard about something similar in KVM.

Comment: What version of ESXi?

Comment: ESXi 6.5 with Linux and Windows guests. This 2 critical VMs are Windows 7 Pro 64-bit systems.

Comment: Any other VMWARE software in the mix?

Comment: If you set the VM to 4 that will guarantee 2 cores will be used.  With it set to 2 you only get a Core with Hyperthreading.  If you want to set the process affinities that’s more difficult